# MySQL Find Average on ids that match

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two columns. One has INT ratings 1-5 and the other is a VenueId. I want to find the average on the ratings where the VenueIds are the same. I have the average working when I identify the VenueId, but don't know how t call all the VenueIds that are equal.

```
connection.query("SELECT AVG(rating) AS value_sum FROM reviews      
  WHERE VenueId = 542", {model: Review}).then(function(projects){
  console.log(projects)
 });
});
```

Comment: You need to read up a little on using aggregators like `GROUP BY`. Easy to get working with a bit of playing around on the SQL command shell. Happy learning!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful...

Comment: I'll read about aggregators, can you combine WHERE and GROUP BY or does GROUP BY replace WHERE?                                                      mysql> SELECT rating FROM reviews WHERE VenueId = 542;
+--------+
| rating |
+--------+
|      5 |
|      4 |
|      4 |
+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT AVG(rating) AS value_sum FROM reviews WHERE VenueId = 542;
+-----------+
| value_sum |
+-----------+
|    4.3333 |
+-----------+

Comment: From your comment, what are the expected results?  You've shown the average and the 3 ratings, but it's still unclear what your desired results should be.

Comment: I have a database of reviews for different venues and I want to find the average review per venue. I then will take the averages and display it in a table with the venue. ie. This is a 4.33 star venue.

Comment: Have you tried the posted solution below -- it should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use Group by with aggregate function here:

```
select venueId, avg(rating) as average
from reviews
group by venueId
```

Comment: I'm still unclear what the expected results should be, but you're missing the `from` clause here.

Comment: *facepalm*.. Added form clause now :)

Comment: It looks like that did it!